# Role based access to url in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a website with asp.net mvc 4. I using basic role management . The thing i want to do is that i want to give access to any url based on users's role.  I was thinking that can we do this via Custom Filter . Because i don't want to write Role attribute on each action . 
So What i think is i am going to define role based urls in database and then on `OnActionExecuted` event i want to check that the requested url is allowed to current user or not . Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible I will not do it for following reasons:

1. `OnActionExecuting` event is pretty early in application execution pipeline. Doing heavy operations that involves going to database should be avoided.
2. As your application grows, it could create maintenance problem. Hundreds of users, hundreds of links, # roles, etc.

Comment: Its ok if you don't agree with my approach , but you should give another idea if you have

Comment: I have 5 `Admin , SuperAdmin , Supervisor , User , QA`

Comment: Have specific controller with actions that are allowed for specific role. Apply role name on controller (if necessary actions) . Its basically what you would see in most cases with Membership.

Comment: I have 15 Controllers , 200+ Actions . I don't think its best way

Comment: Fair enough, so if you have already think of how you will deal with #2, you are good to go then, it is possible. Infact I am using this event for logging all actions with details in DB (turn on only during development). It all works fine if that helps.

Comment: I think @SBirthare has answered your question of whether this is possible. If you want best way to do this, you should change your question to indicate so. We handle some of this by controller inheritance, where each Role has base controller and Role attribute for that controller. Now, this breaks down if you have actions which need to be accessible by multiple Roles in the same controller. Devil is in the details.